# Read properties by dynamic keys in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to know if there is any way in Spring Boot to read property values from properties file by using *Dynamic Keys*. I know properties can be put in `application.properties` and can be read using `@Value("propertyKey")` But my keys are going to be dynamic.

I know about `@PropertySource` to read property values and I can construct my keys dynamically. So is there any way that is provided by Spring Boot?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you can use:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

and then load property from code:

```
env.getProperty("your.property")
```

Answer (score 3):

1- **Register a Properties File via Java Annotations.**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class PropertiesJavaConfig {
    
}
```

2- **Dynamically select the right file at runtime.**

```
@PropertySource({ 
  "classpath:persistence-${envTarget:DB}.properties"
})
```

Comment: for registering proprties file,this works fine

Answer (score 1):

In case you are reading from the application.properties, you just define the environment spring autowired variable as specified by freakman (org.springframework.core.env.Environment). But if you are using a new properties file specific for certain properties, you can use the following code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:filename.properties")
 public class CustomConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;


    public String getProperty(String keyName) {
       return env.getProperty(keyName);
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

1. use private Environment env; class with the import of

> import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

2. Autowire the private Environment class like below

> private Environment envoronment;
>
> public FileSizeValidator(Environment envoronment) {
> this.envoronment = envoronment;   }

3. Use the getProperty method to call the value

> `envoronment.getProperty("property.name")`