# Access value from .properties file in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-el

I have a file named myProperty.properties

```
id.apple=20
id.banana=30
id.orange=40
name=fruit
```

I want to access this property in a service method using Spring's  @Value annotation or ExpressionParser.

Method looks like this

```
public int myMethod(String fruit)
{
    desiredID= "id."+fruit;
    return desiredID;
}
```

For accessing property name
I am using @Value annotation and code looks like this

```
@Value("${name}")
private String name;
```

By this I am easily able to access the property name.
But how should I access the variable property id.fruiname which fruitname is passed in a method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read properties by dynamic keys in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240963/read-properties-by-dynamic-keys-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I dont want to use Environment or Property object since it is loading twice which is decreasing my project's efficiency of computation.
Please give me a solution using Spring's Expression Parser

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

And then read the property value like

```java
public int myMethod(String fruit)
{
    string desiredID= "id."+fruit;
    return Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(desiredID));
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use Environment or Property object since it is loading twice which is decreasing my project's efficiency of computation. Please give me a solution using Spring's Expression Parser

Comment: How it is loading twice and decreasing efficiency of computation?